# How can I filter items with a condition unless another condition is also met in a javascript array?

Tags: javascript

I've this code:

```
payload: data.filter((item) => !isNullOrUndefined(item?.process_detail)
    && !isEqual(item?.process_detail?.status, EVENT_STATE_KEYS.doesNotApply)),
});
   
});
```

Now, I want to only filter items with detail null or undefined when their start_date has already passed, something like:

```
 payload: data.filter((item) => 
 (!isNullOrUndefined(item?.process_detail) &&
 !(formatDate(item?.start_date) < formatDate(new Date())))
    && !isEqual(item?.process_detail?.status, EVENT_STATE_KEYS.doesNotApply)),
   
});
```

The above code is not returning future proccesses that have details  null or undefined.

This is the format of the data:

```
{
"id": 459,
"name": "Future process test",
"date": "2022-11-22T00:00:00.000Z",
"type": "PotentialProcess",
"min_worked_days": 0,
"reminder_days": 0,
"start_date": "2022-10-22T00:00:00.000Z",
"process_detail": null,
"follow_up_process_id": null,
"audience_id": 81,
```

}

Comment: nested if statement.

Comment: Can you add some sample data you are working with?

Comment: I understand the impulse to try and make things a single line but something like this would be much more readable if you broke it down into different statements. The answer would probably be more evident if this was broken up into a couple lines with named vars

Comment: When you say you want to filter items, does that mean you want them returned or discarded?

Comment: @DipanshuKumarSuman sure, just added the example json object.

Comment: Sounds like you want to keep items that are (not null or undefined OR are in the future)

Comment: @James Discarded, i.e., I don't want to return the processes that have a detail null or undefined EXCEPT if they didn't start yet (their start_date IS NOT less than today)

Comment: You can't implement EXCEPT with logical ands, you need to use OR.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
payload = data.filter(
  item =>
    !isNullOrUndefined(item?.process_detail)?
    !isEqual(item?.process_detail?.status, EVENT_STATE_KEYS.doesNotApply):
    !(formatDate(item?.start_date) < formatDate(new Date())) 
);
```

Comment: This doesn't quite work. It evaluates if the item detail is null or undefined, if true it evaluates if the status is applicable, if false it evaluates if the date is not less than today.

What I want is to eliminate the processes with null or undefined details if and only if they already started. All non-applicable proccesses are supposed to have a detail as their status is nested there, so the safe-navigation is already 'validating' it.

Comment: if you only need to return null processes which have already started, what is the purpose of `isEqual`?